# Is there a way to override a template defined into an ansible galaxy role?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, ansible-galaxy

I'm trying to set up a server with ansible and I'd like to use [this galaxy role](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-passenger).

It defines a [template](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-passenger/blob/master/templates/passenger.j2) that I'd like to customize, but I don't know how.

Right now I defined the role into `requirements.yml` and I installed it using:

`ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml`

which installed the role somewhere on my system.

I tried by recreating the folder tree into my repository where I store my playbooks:

```
roles
  |- ansible-role-passenger
     |- templates
        |- passenger.j2
```

but it does not work. When I run my playbook, ansible uses the `passenger.j2` file from inside the galaxy role.

I think I can fork the galaxy role on github and just edit the file `passenger.j2` like I want, but I don't know if this is there is a "better" way to do it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your findings are unfortunately true. Overriding a hardcoded template in a role from a calling playbook is merely impossible **unless the role's author implemented that as a feature**. Note that this is also true for simple files in the `files` directory.

The best way I have found so far: given that the role contains the default template in `templates/passenger.j2`, add a var in `default/main.yml` such as `passenger_config_template: passenger.j2` and use that var in the role. The user can then override that var in its playbook/inventory and use a different name for the template which will be fetched in an other role or directly in a `templates` directory at playbook level.

You can have a look at a [similar issue](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-gitlab/issues/16) and [an accepted PR](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-gitlab/pull/89/files) I once made to @geerlingguy on his ansible-role-gitlab. He might consider doing the same thing on his passenger role (or might accept your PR if you propose one).

Comment: I am currently writing a role in which I want to allow users to override the hardcoded templates folder, if desired. Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Comment: overriding the template folder is going to be hard IMO as this is actually a list ansible looks into.

Comment: @Zeitounator - Sorry, I didn't make myself clear; I'm hoping to allow the user to override the entire templates **folder**. I.e., force the search for `templates/` to start from an arbitrary folder, rather than `{{ role_folder }}`. I had reasoned out your particular method of allowing the use of a single file, but was hoping for more... and it just occurred to me to define a `templates_base` fact with a default of `roles_folder` and provide a complete path to the search. Nevermind. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reply from @Zeitounator above is totally legit.

But in the case where the author of an Ansible role is not responsive or playing dumb, there is another simpler approach.

**Steps:**

1) Execute the role as you would do, don't change anything

2) Write a small piece of Ansible code to simply override any file or template yourself.

Simple approach and is a no-brainer for all.

cheers

Comment: I would prefer forking the role and make the modifications myself, or even write a new one. Your approach is indeed simple and no brainer. But it will override the given templated file twice on each playbook run, blowing away idempotence, with all possible risks in between of running an app, even for only a few seconds, with a bad configuration. That is a total no-go for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Zeitounator response helped me a lot, and I'd like to give more details here (in a comment, the format is too limited), but big thanks to @Zeitounator! :)

To give a concrete example, in your role:

```
roles
`-- passenger
    |-- defaults
    |   `-- main.yml
    |-- tasks
    |   `-- main.yml
    `-- templates
        `-- passenger.j2
```

In the `defaults/main.yml`:

```yaml
passenger_config_template: passenger.j2
```

In the `tasks/main.yml`:

```yaml
- name: Template passenger to /etc/passenger
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: "{{ passenger_config_template }}"
    dest: /etc/passenger
```

By default, Ansible will try to find the file in the role's directory `templates` for the `ansible.builtin.template` module (and `files` directory for the `ansible.builtin.copy` module)

More about Ansible path resolution: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html

Now, in your playbook, to overwrite the default role's template `passenger.j2`, you would have this directory layout:

```
your_ansible_directory
|-- templates
|   `-- passenger.j2  <-- your custom template
|-- ansible.cfg
`-- playbook.yml
```

In the `playbook.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: your_host
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.import_role:
        name: passenger
      vars:
        passenger_config_template: "{{ playbook_dir }}/templates/passenger.j2"
```

Note: I've renamed the role name on purpose to give an example of a good role name: role names shouldn't be prefixed by `ansible-` or `ansible-role-` and should use only `_` (underscore) characters, not `-` (hypen) or `.` (dot) characters.

Read more about role naming:
https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/contributing/creating_role.html#role-names